# hiding image versus drawing it later objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my UITableViewCells I want to show a UIImageView depending on whether an event has occurred. In my custom cell I have an image assigned to the UIImageView (it's a single static local image). I then set the imageview to hidden until I want show it, and then I do imageview.hidden = NO;

My question is whether this affects the performance of the UITableView? Should I only draw the UIImageView as a subview when I need it? Thanks!

Comment: .hidden = YES/NO should be fine, so should .image = theImage/nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not only healthier to do the "`imageview.hidden = NO;`" thing, but it's much better performance wise.

Think of it:  if you add a subview to that cell, you have to remove it before the cell gets recycled to be displayed when a different row gets displayed.  It's far easier to simply do "`imageview.hidden = YES`" at the beginning of each of the calls to your "`cellForRowAtIndex:`" method than it is to go through to remove any unneeded, previously added subviews.

Answer (score 0):

Since you will be recycling your cells, use `UIImage imageNamed` to cache the local image and then hide it as you are doing. You will get the cost of an image load once and then smooth scrolling. The biggest performance hit will be the initial fetch from disk, so best to get it out of the way before the user needs to see it

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Michael for the most part, but do have one caveat.
I would use `imageview.hidden = NO;` That being said, it may not be best in all circumstances.

The actual performance really depends on how many imageViews you actually make visible, it is stylistically more straightforward to just make the view visible. However, if making the image visible is a relatively infrequent event then you can consider delaying loading the image until you need to add it.

For example, if only 2 out of every 50 cells actually gets a visible image, it might be better to delay loading it.